# How to use query params to filter the data?

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller

Assume an entity `Person` with the following fields:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(startegy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;
String name;
String surname;
int age;
```

On the controller, I want the endpoint to be customizable with query parameters so that it can handle every type of combination:

`/api/controller?name=John`

`/api/controller?surname=Doe`

`/api/controller?name=John&age=33&surname=Doe`

Of course, I'd rather avoid having to manually type all combinations.
I found that using `@Spec` you can define something like this:

```java
@Spec(
path = "sample",
params = { "name", "age", "surname" },
spec = //I don't know what is this
)
```

But this doesn't seem to handle all combinations, rather I have to put them together myself.
Defining one spec for each field seems to work, but again that doesn't handle combinations.

What am I missing? How can I achieve this?

EDIT: I've found out about [QueryDSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe), but I can't seem to import it into my project. I've added the following dependencies to my pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Spring 2.3.3.RELEASE

EDIT: I have fixed the dependencies, however, upon launching the app I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Did not find a query class net.mydom.net.entity.QUser for domain class net.mydom.net.entity.User!
```

This is my user entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "enterprise_id")
    private String enterpriseID;

    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private Short rol;
    private Short status;
    private String language;
    private String email;
    private Date lastLogin;
    private String image;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [DslQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe)

`pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`UserRepository.java`

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User> {

}
```

`UserController.java`

```java
@GetMapping("/dsl")
public List<User> getUserDsl( @QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate) {
    return service.getUsersDsl(predicate);
}
```

`UserService.java`

```java
public List<User> getUsersDsl(Predicate predicate) {
    List<User> actualList = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterable<User> iterable = repository.findAll(predicate);
    iterable.forEach(actualList::add);
    return actualList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want a way to map the attributes from `Person` as query params in your API calls.

Is recommended that you add a DTO for this that should be like.

```java
public class PersonDTO {
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;

    // constructors, getter and setters

}
```

Now you can include this `DTO` as parameters from your endpoint method, which would be recognized, should be something like this:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/controller")
class YourController {

    @GetMapping
    public PersonDTO findPerson(PersonDTO personDTO) {
        //the logic you want to add
        return personDTO;
    }

}
```

You can add on `PersonDTO` attributes the [javax.validation.constraints](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) with `@Valid` annotation on you DTO to add some validations.

Comment: No, I'm not looking to map the object. What I want is a way to turn the path variables into a query, dynamically. If you get a query param with name and surname, I want to be able to query the db with a `select * from Person where name = ? and surname = ?`

Comment: I assume he has a table displaying user's info, which will display the users that fit the searched criteria. Those criteria can be searched by name/ by age/ by surname/ by name and age/ by name and surname/.... The number of combinations would shoot up with increasing params so he doesn't want to do the query manually for each combination

Comment: Ok just for be sure is I think is query params instead of path variables.

Automatically i don't know if there's a way, but you can test if the parameter is present on the `DTO`  and increment your query, something like this:

```java
public SomePerson {
    public String returnQuery(PersonDTO person){
      String start = "select * from Person where 1 = 1";
      String where = "";

      if (person.getName() != null) {
         where += " and name = ?";
      }

      //other parameters

      return start + where;
    }
}
```